# NSMutableArray error, keep saying error out of bounds

Tags: objective-c

I really cant see the forest through the trees as they say.
first off, here is my code :

```
 -(NSMutableArray*)getWaranty:(NSString*)string start:(NSString*)start and:(NSString*)end{
NSMutableArray *waranties = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSRange startRange = [string rangeOfString:start];
NSRange valueRange;
valueRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length; //beginpunt
NSRange eindRange = [string rangeOfString:end];
valueRange.length = eindRange.location - valueRange.location;
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]init];
result = nil;
if(valueRange.location != NSNotFound){
    if(valueRange.length != NSNotFound){
        result = [string substringWithRange:valueRange];
        NSString *testResult = [[NSString alloc]init];
        testResult = result;

        NSString* beginTrim = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim2 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim3 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim4 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim5 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim6 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim7 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim8 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim9 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString* beginTrim10 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        beginTrim = [testResult stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<li class=\"TopTwoWarrantyListItem\">"withString:@""];
        beginTrim1 = [beginTrim stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<b>"withString:@""];
        beginTrim2 = [beginTrim1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<li>"withString:@""];
        beginTrim3 = [beginTrim2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</li>"withString:@""];
        beginTrim4 = [beginTrim3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</b>"withString:@""];
        beginTrim5 = [beginTrim4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<a href=\"javascript:SelectTabFromLink(5);\" id=\"SeeWarrantyTab\" class=\"uif_link\">"withString:@""];
        beginTrim6 = [beginTrim5 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</a>"withString:@""];
        NSString *lang =[[NSString alloc]init];
        lang= @"nl";
        if(lang == @"nl"){
            beginTrim7 = [beginTrim6 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".  Raadpleeg het tabblad Garantie voor meer informatie."withString:@""];
        }
        beginTrim8 = [beginTrim7 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</div>"withString:@""];
        beginTrim9 = [beginTrim8 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n"withString:@""];
        beginTrim10 = [beginTrim9 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *warant = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString *theWarant = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString *hoev = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString *lic = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString *datum = [[NSString alloc]init];
        if(lang == @"nl"){
            //split met garantie
            warant = [beginTrim10 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  garantie met einddatum op"withString:@""];
            NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
            array = [warant componentsSeparatedByString:@"                                                                                                                 "];
            NSInteger hoeveel = [array count];
            if(hoeveel != 0){
                hoev = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hoeveel];
                [waranties addObject:hoev];
                for(int i = 0; i < hoeveel; i++){
                    if([array objectAtIndex:i] != NULL){
                        theWarant = [array objectAtIndex:i];
                        NSArray *specArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
                        specArray = [theWarant componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
                        lic = [specArray objectAtIndex:0];
                        datum = [specArray objectAtIndex:1];
                        [waranties addObject:lic];
                        [waranties addObject:datum];
                        NSLog(@" de waraiens 1 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:0]);
                        NSLog(@" de waraiens 1 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:1]);
                    }
                    else{

                    }

                }
            NSLog(@" de waraiens 1 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:0]);
            NSLog(@" de waraiens 2 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:1]);
            NSLog(@" de waraiens 3 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:2]);
            NSLog(@" de waraiens 4 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:3]);
            NSLog(@" de waraiens 5 :%@", [waranties objectAtIndex:4]);
            return waranties;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The code should return somthing like :

2013-03-12 21:12:51.783 DellSupportApp[6254:c07]  de waraiens 1 :2

2013-03-12 21:12:51.785 DellSupportApp[6254:c07]  de waraiens 2 :Dell Business Support/ProSupport

2013-03-12 21:12:51.785 DellSupportApp[6254:c07]  de waraiens 3 :30/07/2009

2013-03-12 21:12:51.785 DellSupportApp[6254:c07]  de waraiens 4 :Next Business Day

2013-03-12 21:12:51.786 DellSupportApp[6254:c07]  de waraiens 5 :30/07/2009

But the tricky thing is. It only works like 1 out of 10 times...
the method is called in this function :

```
-(NSMutableArray*) parseIt: (NSString*) toPars {
NSMutableArray *waranties = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *beginTitle = @"<title>";
NSString *eindTitle = @"</title>";
NSString *title = [self getTitle:toPars start:beginTitle and:eindTitle];
if(title != NULL){
    NSLog(@"de title = %@", title);
    [waranties addObject:title];
    NSString *try = [waranties objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"de title = %@", try);
}

NSString *beginWar = @"<div class=\"TopTwoWarrantySummaryDiv\">";
NSString *eindWar = @"<div class=\"RequestWarrantyExtensionDiv\">";
NSMutableArray *warrant = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
warrant = [self getWaranty:toPars start:beginWar and:eindWar];
if(warrant != NULL){
    [waranties addObject:warrant];
     NSLog(@" de warant %@ ", [waranties objectAtIndex:1]);
}
return waranties;
```

I find it very fisgy that it enters the first method shown here, about 10 times, while i only ask it once...
I am searvhin the problems for over 4 hours now, getting tired of some erros, well actually an error is mostly not shown...

Please point me my errors...

Comment: Just a side not because it does not solve your problem. There is no point in allocating and initializing all those 10 strings. When calling `[NSString stringWith...` a new object is allicated and initialized anyway. On the contrary - without ARC this may even leak.

Comment: Can you please show the error message with that out of bounce? And did you figure out in these 4 hours where exactly the error is thrown?

Comment: hey oke, i will remove the init of those strings. For the rest : the funny thing is sometimes it shows nothing(only title) sometimes it points to a mistake in memory (error is  0x10d2aab:  movl   (%esi), %ecx and it poitn oud bad adress ex :) and then in like 1 in 15 try's it works)

Comment: Did you already enable zombies on your xcode project? If not then do so. You will get by far better error messages and better hints on where the error comes up. When you have this error in the machine code, does the call stack give you a hint on where in your code the system routine was called? And finally add an "all exceptions" breakpoint. And on break press continue until the error message is actually on screen. Doing so you see the error and most probably find the piece of code that caused it.

Comment: Can you help me maybe? i have found a problem : valueRange loc and length isnt always the same. sometimes loc is 2,4 thousand and lentgh is 0, then it gives the pointer. when loc is 2,1 and length is 0 it downs nothing, when length is 500,000(+-) and length is 428 it works fine, i just cant figure out why the values can change???

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I have concerns about how brittle it is.  It's looking for a series of spaces to separate the warranties, but is that really the best way to split the data?

Besides that you're making assumptions on those splits.  For example:

```
specArray = [theWarant componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
```

is assigned and you check both index 0 and 1, but never make sure there are 2 values in the array.

Your `NSLog`s at the bottom also don't check array bounds before they're processed.

Spaces make notoriously bad delimiters for data.  If you're looking to parse html there are tools out there that might do the job better.

Comment: Check out HPPLE for HTML Parsing

Comment: oke, but when i use NSLogs they all show correct answers. its when i put them in the arrays that things go loose... :s

Comment: Could this be because of the separator?

Comment: Can you help me maybe? i have found a problem : valueRange loc and length isnt always the same. sometimes loc is 2,4 thousand and lentgh is 0, then it gives the pointer. when loc is 2,1 and length is 0 it downs nothing, when length is 500,000(+-) and length is 428 it works fine, i just cant figure out why the values can change???

Answer (score 0):

This statement will fail with out of bounds in the event that waranties is an empty array before its execution:

```
if(warrant != NULL){
    [waranties addObject:warrant];
     NSLog(@" de warant %@ ", [waranties objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

The first object in an array has the index 0, not 1.

And that will happen every time when not title is found. This may not be your problem if there is always a title. However, it is saver to code:

```
if(warrant != NULL){
    [waranties addObject:warrant];
     NSLog(@" de warant %@ ", [waranties objectAtIndex:[caranties count]-1]);
}
```

or probalby even better:

```
if(warrant != NULL){
    [waranties addObject:warrant];
     NSLog(@" de warant %@ ", [waranties lastObject]);
}
```

Anyway, as this is debug output only, it is certainly not the root cause of your problem. I have just choosen an answer instead of a comment because of its formatting capabilities.

Comment: waranties is never empty, there is always the title in objectAtIndex:0, thats the strange thin, that code works every time. The method for getting warrant array (first method shown here) doenst always works, and that gives the error i guess :s (already many thanks for helping me!)

Comment: Can you help me maybe? i have found a problem : valueRange loc and length isnt always the same. sometimes loc is 2,4 thousand and lentgh is 0, then it gives the pointer. when loc is 2,1 and length is 0 it downs nothing, when length is 500,000(+-) and length is 428 it works fine, i just cant figure out why the values can change???

Comment: Without knowing the data, I cannot say anything about that. You could help those who want to help by replying to their questions. On the other hand you should consider working with an established html parsing framework such as hpple.